# After form is submitted, result is opening up in a new window as well as the target frame

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit

Before submitting the form 2 things are  being set

1. Action
2. Target

Here target is set to name of an iFrame .
And .submit() is called

Code

```
document.forms[0].action = <action>
document.forms[0].target = "frameName"
document.forms[0].submit()
```

The result is opening up in both new window and targetted frame.

How to prevent it from opening up in new window and only show the result in targetted frame?
Please help

Solution I tried.

1. event.preventDefault()
   Basically before submitting the form

```
document.forms[0].addEventListener("submit",function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    document.forms[0].submit()
});
```

This prevented it from opening in new window but there was no result in the targetted tab... It was blank

Comment: There must be something else opening the new window.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].